# Building deb package gives fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2

Tags: 12.04, dpkg, packaging, deb

I am trying to create my first deb package of https://github.com/manojgudi/sandhi. After this command - dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot  it stops with the following error -

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: error: no dependency information found for /usr/local/lib/libuhd.so.003 (used by debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_uhd.so).
dh_shlibdeps: dpkg-shlibdeps -Tdebian/sandhi.substvars debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_uhd.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_network.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_misc.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_packet.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_jit.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_sources.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/modules/grex/libgrex_math.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/gras/python/grex/_UHDTypes.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libgnuradio-filter-3.6.4.2.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libgnuradio-core-3.6.4.2.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libvolk.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libgnuradio-qtgui-3.6.4.2.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libgruel-3.6.4.2.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libpmc.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libgras.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libgnuradio-blocks-3.6.4.2.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_TimeTag.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_PyBlock.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_TopBlock.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_Factory.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_Tags.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_Block.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_SBuffer.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_HierBlock.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_PyHierBlocks.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_Element.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gras/_GRAS_ThreadPool.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gruel/pmt/_pmt_swig.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/gr/_gnuradio_core_runtime.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/gr/_gnuradio_core_io.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/gr/_gnuradio_core_hier.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/gr/_gnuradio_core_filter.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/gr/_gnuradio_core_general.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/gr/_gnuradio_core_gengen.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/filter/_filter_swig.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/qtgui/_qtgui_swig.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/fft/_fft_swig.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/gnuradio/blocks/_blocks_swig.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCIntegers.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCNumericArray.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCList.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCTuple.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCSet.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCPool.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCFloats.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCBool.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCNone.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCString.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCIndex.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCComplex.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/pyshared/python2.7/PMC/_PMCDict.so debian/sandhi/usr/lib/libgnuradio-fft-3.6.4.2.so.0.0.0 debian/sandhi/usr/bin/volk_profile debian/sandhi/usr/bin/gnuradio-config-info returned exit code 2
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Comment: Why it does need that lib from `/usr/local/`?